# Pyspark: Feature Engineer Point-in-Time Metrics

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, feature-engineering

I have been attempting for the longest time to model point in time data. To exemplify this process, imagine 4 different customers (some returning, some new ones) making purchases from a store (as shown below)

[image]

I am attempting, using Pyspark to partition my code by ID, and create two features: mean (at that point in time) purchase, and total purchase. The result would show as below:

[image]

I have nailed down the Total_Purchase_1 column by simply doing a cumulative sum, but I cannot for the life of me, get the point in time mean (Mean_Purchase_1) where the mean is calculated only using that Date's lag values.

Has anyone ever had experience working with feature engineering tasks of this sort? I'm a big R guy and have experience handling it with dplyr or even Pandas in Python, but I'm trying to optimize this using Pyspark. Thanks!

Comment: How you want to calculate the mean purchase ? if that for a group of customer? i.e , for B55 - it's always 500, if that is the case , I am not understanding how other two values are coming - 650 and 100 for the 2nd and 3rd row of mean purchase 1.. would be great if you could help clarify the logic

Comment: Hey @dsk thanks for asking. The metrics are based on the current mean at that date. For instance, 10/2/2015 was the client B55's first purchase, so their mean was equal to their purchase (1000/1)

On 1/05/2016 was their second purchase (for $300), so at that point in time, their mean was (1000+300)/2 = 650

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response ..I have shared a solution , can you please check and help accept and upvote if that worked for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a working solution for you , use **`window function`** and **`mean()`**

## Create the DF Here

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame([("B55","2018-05-28", 200),
                           ("B55","2016-05-01", 300),
                           ("B55","2015-02-10", 1000),
                            ("A37","2017-12-30", 2100),
                            ("A37","2016-06-21", 2000)
                           ],[ "id","date","value"])
df.show()
_w = W.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")
df = df.withColumn("mean", F.mean("value").over(_w))
df.show()
```

## Input

```
+---+----------+-----+
| id|      date|value|
+---+----------+-----+
|B55|2018-05-28|  200|
|B55|2016-05-01|  300|
|B55|2015-02-10| 1000|
|A37|2017-12-30| 2100|
|A37|2016-06-21| 2000|
+---+----------+-----+
```

## Output

```
+---+----------+-----+------+
| id|      date|value|  mean|
+---+----------+-----+------+
|A37|2016-06-21| 2000|2000.0|
|A37|2017-12-30| 2100|2050.0|
|B55|2015-02-10| 1000|1000.0|
|B55|2016-05-01|  300| 650.0|
|B55|2018-05-28|  200| 500.0|
+---+----------+-----+------+
```

Comment: Great to see that it helped you :) would you care about giving an upvote :) to the answer, will highly appreciate that!